# How do I use first-order perturbation theory to compute the first four energy levels related to a potential well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, perturbation-theory

I came across a problem whose statement is as follows:

An electron moves in the potential well $P (x) = -\delta$ for $- a <x <0$ and $P (x) = \delta$ for $0 <x <a$ (Fig. 13.7). Use first-order perturbation theory to compute the first four energy levels. Set up the expression for the first-order expansion coefficients for the lowest energy state.[image]

I was trying to use the following equation that I saw throughout the chapter (number 13):

$$
E'_n - E_n = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi_n^{*} f(x) \psi_n dx
$$

Treating $f(x) = P(x)$ and the $\psi_n$ function equal to

$$
\psi_n = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}} \sin{\left( \frac{n \pi}{a} x\right)}
$$

However, this gives me zero as a result of $E'_n - E_n$.

How can I proceed?

The textbook I'm using is **Richtmyer F.K.,Kennard E.H.,Cooper J.N. - *Introduction to modern physics-McGraw-Hill* (1969)**.

Comment: Isn’t that $\psi_n$ for a square well from $x=0$ to $x=a$?

Comment: That's right. First I was trying to use this $\psi_n$ everywhere, but then I realized that this is not good. And I'm having doubts about the usage of this in some specifc region in the figure. I mean, could I use it in the $x=-a$ to $x=0$ interval?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a perturbation $P(x)$, then to 1st order, the energy shifts are:

$$ E^{(1)}_n - E^{(0)}_n = \langle n|P(x)|n\rangle $$

but you have to use the $|n\rangle$ that solve your unperturbed hamiltonian, $H^{(0)}(x)$, not the ones that solve $H^{(0)}(x'=\frac 1 2 (x+a))$.

You can either transform your $\psi_n(x')$ into $\psi(x)$ to match $H(x)$, or you can transform $H(x)$ to $H(x')$ to match you $\psi_n(x')$.

Note that as stated, you have an odd perturbation, so if an unperturbed solution spends 1/2 its time in the left (right) side of the box, the half of the time, the energy is lowered (raised), so you would expect the 1st order perturbations to be zero, esp. for *even* solutions, since that should be zero by symmetry.

You would expect the 1st order perturbation to the wave function to shift some weight to $x<0$, since the potential is deeper there.

Comment: You'd expect the 1st order perturbation to the _ground state_ to shift towards $x\lt 0 $. For excited states the classical logic is that the particle moves faster in the lower potential regions and so spends _less_ time there, thus they should shift to the right.